# How to remove specific part of legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I am using a seaborn scatterplot and just started using different point sizes.

```
sns.scatterplot(x='X [um]', y='Y [um]', hue='label', size='size', data=data)
```

All works perfectly but I'd like to remove the 'size' from the legend seen in picture:
[image]

The upper part with CH1, etc. shall remain the same but I'd want the lower part where the sizes are listed to vanish.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove one out of two legends from Seaborn Scatterplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163460/remove-one-out-of-two-legends-from-seaborn-scatterplot)

Answer (score 6):

I use the `get_legend_handles_labels()` functionality to index the labels. Using indexing, I ensure that the final printed image only contains the first 13 labels in your legend.

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='X [um]', y='Y [um]', hue='label', size='size', data=data)

# extract the existing handles and labels
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# slice the appropriate section of l and h to include in the legend
ax.legend(h[0:13], l[0:13] ,bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

plt.show()
```