# Remove a legend section from a seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

Using the 'tips' dataset as a toy model, I generate the following plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(dark=.3, light=.8, as_cmap=True)
g = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="sex", hue="smoker", size = 'tip',sizes=(320, 600), data=tips)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., fontsize=13)
plt.show(g)
```

This image is exactly what I need. However, I want to remove the `size = 'tip'` from the legend and only keep the smoker. Essentially, remove those black circles labeled 0.0 to 12.0. How do I ensure my legend has only one variable of my choosing?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to find a fix by indexing the labels in the legend.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(dark=.3, light=.8, as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="sex", hue="smoker", size='tip', sizes=(320, 600), data=tips)

# extract the existing handles and labels
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# slice the appropriate section of l and h to include in the legend
ax.legend(h[0:3], l[0:3], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., fontsize=13)
plt.show()
```

[image]